# When would ACTION_OUTSIDE be triggered?

Tags: android

I don't understand when ACTION_OUTSIDE is triggered. Please give me an example.

The doc's give this cryptic description:

> Constant for getAction(): A movement
>   has happened outside of the normal
>   bounds of the UI element. This does
>   not provide a full gesture, but only
>   the initial location of the
>   movement/touch.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_OUTSIDE

Comment: Wouldn't this be when the movement starts from the screen, then is dragged off screen?

Comment: Or outside the bounds of any view element. Like if you press a button, then move your finger off it before releasing.

Comment: I've tried them both, but it never triggers.

Comment: @Geobits is wrong; moving outside a control doesn't trigger this.

Answer (score 19):

I believe it is only used for clicking outside of the current activity (for example a dialog). Check out [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH)

Comment: This is correct and should be accepted as a correct answer.