# Android: Detect if user touches and drags out of button region?

Tags: android, button, gestures

In Android, how can we detect if a user touches on button and drags out of region of this button?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

<strike>Check the MotionEvent.MOVE_OUTSIDE:</strike> Check the MotionEvent.MOVE:

```
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
            // User moved outside bounds
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

NOTE: If you want to target Android 4.0, a whole world of new possibilities opens:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_HOVER_ENTER

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I only can catch ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE but not ACTION_OUTSIDE.

Comment: It's available from API Level 3 onwards: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_OUTSIDE

Comment: According to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162497/when-would-action-outside-be-triggered/8059266#8059266) I believe we only can use ACTION_OUTSIDE to detect if touch is outside an Activity, not a view.

Comment: See FrostRocket's answer for an update to rect.contains test to make this work for individual views that aren't positioned at the origin.

Comment: I believe if you want to get `ACTION_OUTSIDE` you will need to use `getActionMasked()`. Or you could compared the masks instead: `if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)`. This is because `ACTION_OUTSIDE` will never trigger without already having another action, so it will be masked.

Comment: @ChadBingham Not receiving `ACTION_OUTSIDE` when dragging out of the button, either with `getAction()` or `getActionMasked()`

Comment: p.s. confirmed - `ACTION_OUTSIDE ` doesn't work for views.

Answer (score 22):

The answer posted by Entreco needed some slight tweaking in my case.  I had to substitute:

```
if(!rect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
```

for

```
if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY()))
```

because `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` only apply to the ImageView itself, not the entire screen.

Comment: +1 thanks, that's the more universal approach and works in custom view implementations too

Answer (score 13):

I had this same problem as the OP whereby I wanted to know when (1) a particular `View` was touched down as well as either (2a) when the down touch was released on the `View` or (2b) when the down touch moved outside the bounds of the `View`. I brought together the various answers in this thread to create a simple extension of `View.OnTouchListener` (named `SimpleTouchListener`) so that others don't have to fiddle around with the `MotionEvent` object. The source for this class can be found [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-utils) or at the bottom of this answer.

To use this class, simply set it as the parameter of the `View.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener)` method follows:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new SimpleTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDownTouchAction() {
        // do something when the View is touched down
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpTouchAction() {
        // do something when the down touch is released on the View
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelTouchAction() {
        // do something when the down touch is canceled
        // (e.g. because the down touch moved outside the bounds of the View
    }
});
```

Here is the source of the class which you are welcome to add to your project:

```
public abstract class SimpleTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    /**
     * Flag determining whether the down touch has stayed with the bounds of the view.
     */
    private boolean touchStayedWithinViewBounds;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStayedWithinViewBounds = true;
                onDownTouchAction();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (touchStayedWithinViewBounds) {
                    onUpTouchAction();
                }
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (touchStayedWithinViewBounds
                        && !isMotionEventInsideView(view, event)) {
                    onCancelTouchAction();
                    touchStayedWithinViewBounds = false;
                }
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                onCancelTouchAction();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method which is called when the {@link View} is touched down.
     */
    public abstract void onDownTouchAction();

    /**
     * Method which is called when the down touch is released on the {@link View}.
     */
    public abstract void onUpTouchAction();

    /**
     * Method which is called when the down touch is canceled,
     * e.g. because the down touch moved outside the bounds of the {@link View}.
     */
    public abstract void onCancelTouchAction();

    /**
     * Determines whether the provided {@link MotionEvent} represents a touch event
     * that occurred within the bounds of the provided {@link View}.
     *
     * @param view  the {@link View} to which the {@link MotionEvent} has been dispatched.
     * @param event the {@link MotionEvent} of interest.
     * @return true iff the provided {@link MotionEvent} represents a touch event
     * that occurred within the bounds of the provided {@link View}.
     */
    private boolean isMotionEventInsideView(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect(
                view.getLeft(),
                view.getTop(),
                view.getRight(),
                view.getBottom()
        );

        return viewRect.contains(
                view.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(),
                view.getTop() + (int) event.getY()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a great answer, especially for people working with the issue for when ACTION_CANCEL not triggering as it should.

Comment: Yes it is a great answer!

Answer (score 8):

I added some logging in my OnTouch and found out that `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` was being hit. That's good enough for me...

Comment: You'll get a `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` callback if your `View` is contained within a parent `ViewGroup` like `ScrollView` which is interested in stealing move touches from its children but otherwise there's no guarantee you'll get a `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` callback in your `View`.

Comment: The only solution that worked out for me, thanks saved me

Answer (score 3):

The top 2 answers are fine except when the view is inside a scrollview: when scrolling takes place because you move your finger, it is still registered as a touch event but not as a MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE event. So to improve the answer (which is only needed if your view is inside a scroll element):

```
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

    } else if(rect != null && !rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
        // User moved outside bounds
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tested this on Android 4.3 and Android 4.4

I haven't noticed any differences between Moritz's answer and to top 2 but this also applies for his answer:

```
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

    } else if (rect != null){
        v.getHitRect(rect);
        if(rect.contains(
                Math.round(v.getX() + event.getX()),
                Math.round(v.getY() + event.getY()))) {
            // inside
        } else {
            // outside
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've just implemented this code on a button which is contained in an item of a RecyclerView and works perfectly. I just wanted to say that  you can get rid of the new Rect on the **ACTION_DOWN** if you add it before getHitRect.  
    **Rect rect = new Rect();
    getHitRect(rect);**

Answer (score 3):

### Reuseable Kotlin Solution

I started with two custom extension functions:

```
val MotionEvent.up get() = action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

fun MotionEvent.isIn(view: View): Boolean {
    val rect = Rect(view.left, view.top, view.right, view.bottom)
    return rect.contains((view.left + x).toInt(), (view.top + y).toInt())
}
```

Then listen to touches on the view. This will only fire if ACTION_DOWN was originally on the view. When you release your finger, it will check if it was still on the view.

```
myView.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    if (motionEvent.up && !motionEvent.isIn(view)) {
        // Talk your action here
    }
    false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
view.setClickable(true);
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!v.isPressed()) {
            Log.e("onTouch", "Moved outside view!");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

`view.isPressed` uses `view.pointInView` and includes some touch slop. If you don't want slop, just copy the logic from the internal `view.pointInView` (which is public, but hidden so it's not a part of the official API and could disappear at any time).

```
view.setClickable(true);
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.setTag(true);
        } else {
            boolean pointInView = event.getX() >= 0 && event.getY() >= 0
                    && event.getX() < (getRight() - getLeft())
                    && event.getY() < (getBottom() - getTop());
            boolean eventInView = ((boolean) v.getTag()) && pointInView;
            Log.e("onTouch", String.format("Dragging currently in view? %b", pointInView));
            Log.e("onTouch", String.format("Dragging always in view? %b", eventInView));
            v.setTag(eventInView);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from @FrostRocket is correct you should use view.getX() and Y to account for translations changes as well:

```
 view.getHitRect(viewRect);
 if(viewRect.contains(
         Math.round(view.getX() + event.getX()),
         Math.round(view.getY() + event.getY()))) {
   // inside
 } else {
   // outside
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `View.OnTouchListener` that you can use to see if `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` was sent while the user had his/her finger outside of the view:

```
private OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private Rect rect;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v == null) return true;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (rect != null
                    && !rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(),
                        v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                // The motion event was outside of the view, handle this as a non-click event

                return true;
            }
            // The view was clicked.
            // TODO: do stuff
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If drag to outside of view, 'ACTION_CANCEL' event call. So need disallow parent view to intercept touch event:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            (parent as? ViewGroup?)?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            (parent as? ViewGroup?)?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        }
        else -> {
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

and then you can check touch point is outside of your view or not!