# Limiting onTouch ACTION_MOVE to one View

Tags: android

I'm implementing an app that uses part of the screen as a touchpad for the user to manipulate a mechanical device. I want to limit the touchpad behavior to only that `View`.

But if the user puts his finger down **inside** that `View` and moves it **outside** the `View`  in my `onTouch()` `Handler` I continue to get `ACTION_MOVE` events when the user is dragging outside the `View`.

And the `View` ID passed-in to `onTouch()` is still that of the original `View` even though the events are coming from outside that `View's` bounds!

Why does it do this and how can I constrain events to only within the bounds of that one `View`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the gray "highlighting" that's appeared over various words in my question?  (I didn't put it there)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer eleswhere on SO -

[Android: Detect if user touches and drags out of button region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410200/android-how-to-detect-if-use-touches-and-drags-out-of-button-region)

I had to move the "return false;" statement up inside the curly braces where  "// User moved outside bounds", but otherwise I was able to use it intact.   So, thanks to [Entreco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563904/entreco).

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Each fragment has own UI event handler.
I hope that's enough for you :)

Comment: Reading the documentation on Fragments, per your link, it looks like that won't address the problem, because each fragment gets its own View hierarchy and since the events are still coming from the original View even when outside that View's bounds, they'll still get processed in that same fragment even when outside that View's bounds.