# Discarding part of content that are outside a view boundary

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-view

I am creating layout dynamically in android, in which i am adding views to relative layout.

Views are having contents.

I am having issue with contents that goes out of views boundary are overlapping with other views.How can i define boundary for my views so any PART OF CONTENT that goes out of views boundary will be discarded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410200/android-how-to-detect-if-use-touches-and-drags-out-of-button-region

Comment: Try giving a fixed height to your view